# Resizing font size by jQuery does not work on Chrome and Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, browser

I was trying to implement font resize functionality on a website. I have written some jQuery code that does works perfect on Mozila but does't work on other browsers like Chrome, Safari. On Chrome and Safari it resize the font only on first click. Here is my code. 

**JQuery Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('[id="fontlarge"]').click(function(){
        jQuery('*').each(function(){
            var fontSize = jQuery(this).css('font-size');
            fontSize =  fontSize.substr(0,2);
            //alert(fontSize);
            if(fontSize<=13)
            {
                var currentSize = jQuery(this).css('font-size');
                var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)+.2;
                jQuery(this).css('font-size', currentSize);
            }
        });
    }); 

jQuery('[id="fontsmall"]').click(function(){
        jQuery('*').each(function(){
            var fontSize = jQuery(this).css('font-size');
            fontSize =  fontSize.substr(0,2);
            //alert(fontSize);
            if(fontSize>=12)
            {
                var currentSize = jQuery(this).css('font-size');
                var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)-.2;
                jQuery(this).css('font-size', currentSize);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<span id="fontsmall" style="cursor:pointer;">-</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="fontlarge" style="cursor:pointer;">+</span>
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, since it seems browser specific, but... instead of `[id="fontlarge"]` you can just use `#fontlarge`. Same with `[id="fontsmall"]` and `#fontsmall`.

Comment: @DevlshOne Well the DOM element selector is not a problem because i am able to fire event by both types of selector #fontlarge and [id="fontlarge"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use integer number for resizing the font, it should be resolved if you can.

I noticed one more thing into your code which is below:-

fontSize.substr(0,2)

it will always return a two digit number even you have a font size 10.2, 10.4 etc.

So this is the reason because of that browser extending your font size first time only. I am not sure why is working on firefox but it should not work any where.

Please use fontSize.slice(0,-2)